# Label coordinates that fall in a specific shapefile

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, pyshp

I have a dataframe for individuals, each individual has X and Y coordinates, and I have a .shp file
that has a number of polygons.

individuals dataframe look like:

| ind_ID | x_coordinates | y_coordinates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.333 | 6.572711 |
| 2 | 3.4444 | 6.57273 |

the .shp file looks like:

| Code | shape length | shape area |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 222 | .22 | .5432 |
| 2322 | .54322 | .4342 |
| 122 | .65656 | .43 |
| 2122 | .5445 | .5678 |

What I want to do is to add a new column to the data frame, in order to label each coordinate with the linked `Code` of .shp file that this coordinate fall inside it.
to do so, I built this code :

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
import csv
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
import shapefile
from shapely.geometry import shape # shape() is a function to convert geo objects through the interface
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import shapefile as shp


Individual = pd.read_csv("dataframe.csv")
sf = shapefile.Reader('path to the shape file.shp')
sf.shapes()
len(sf.shapes())

# function to read the shapefile
def read_shapefile(sf):
    """
    Read a shapefile into a Pandas dataframe with a 'coords' 
    column holding the geometry information. This uses the pyshp
    package
    """
    fields = [x[0] for x in sf.fields][1:]
    records = sf.records()
    shps = [s.points for s in sf.shapes()]
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=fields, data=records)
    df = df.assign(coords=shps)
    return df

df = read_shapefile(sf)
df.shape
```

I used the `read_shapefile` function to find all x,y points inside each feature. Output dataframe:

| Code | shape length | shape area | cooded |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 222 | .22 | .5432 | 3.23232,2.72323,3.931226,2.543,3.435534 .... |
| 2322 | .54322 | .4342 | 3.23232,2.72322,3.111226,2.343,3.12312 ... |
| 122 | .65656 | .43 | 3.2323,2.23325,3.1212,2.1221,3.12321 ... |
| 2122 | .5445 | .5678 | 3.9232,2.23232,2.931226,1.2123,3.213 ... |

The next step is to check each individual, whether it falls inside any coded points,
if yes, add a new column to the  Individual dataframe containing the corresponding `Code` of the shapefile.
I need the help of this part ^^",
I started as checking x,y in the sh data coords

```
Individual.["X","Y"].isin(sf .["coords"]).astype(int)
```

I couldn't check as there is an error.
the output need is : individuals dataframe looks like:

| ind_ID | x_coordinates | y_coordinates | Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.333 | 6.572711 | 222 |
| 2 | 3.4444 | 6.57273 | 122 |